# Duplicate words removal with python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I try to remove duplicate words in each row of a column. I use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

#df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', dtype='unicode', engine='openpyxl')

data = {'duplicate_column':["Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot", 'Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML', 'L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI', 'Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml', 'Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df ['new_column'] = df['duplicate_column'].str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()))
```

However, there a few situations, case sensitive and not only for which, this method is not working. For example:

```
Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot
Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML
L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI
Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml
Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set
```

The correct output for the above should be, keeping the first occurrence:

```
Adidas Women's A004 Snow Boot
Amul Milk, 100ml
L-OCCITANE CREMA MANI
Corneto Ice Cream, 300 ml
Béaba, Set di 6 Contenitori
```

Can you please help on optimizing the below code? It is working for simple situations not for the example above.

Comment: Per your examples , it will be extremely hard to do it with using NLP library (NLTK,SPACY etc..)

Comment: Yeah, there are many little things that need to be accounted for.  I was going to provide an answer but I'd have to spend too much time making sure I account for each issue you've presented.

Comment: @piRSquared is there any function that could be built to convert  in lower and scenarious like L-Occitane or L'Occitane in Loccitane and then remove duplicates?

Comment: I undeleted my answer so you get some feedback.  It misses the `'300 ml'` with the space.

Answer (score 0):

### Make `str.lower` case and remove punctuation

```
punct = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{}~´'
transtab = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(punct, ''))

df['new_column'] = [
    ' '.join(dict.fromkeys(s.translate(transtab).lower().split()))
    for s in df['duplicate_column']
]

df

                        duplicate_column                      new_column
0   Adidas Women's Womens A004 Snow Boot    adidas womens a004 snow boot
1                Amul Milk, 100ml, 100ML                 amul milk 100ml
2       L-OCCITANE L´Occitane CREMA MANI            loccitane crema mani
3   Corneto Ice Cream Ice, 300 ml -300ml  corneto ice cream 300 ml 300ml
4  Béaba BÉABA, Set di 6 Contenitori,set   béaba set di 6 contenitoriset
```

Comment: thank you so much. This would be great but can we maintain the casing and commas in the final output somehow?